# In a ARC project a class (A) inherits from another class (B) contained in a non-arc file

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, automatic-ref-counting, didreceivememorywarning

When I use A in my project and I simulate memory warning in simulator, the App often crashes in [super didReceiveMemoryWarning].
Is there anything I should take pay attention if I want to inherit a class from a non-ARC file in a ARC project?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not following the logical connection between didReceiveMemoryWarning and the ARC/non-ARC question.
2. The ARC/non-ARC question is duplicative of previous [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790620/subclass-non-arc-file-into-arc-project-in-xcode-4).
3. Beyond the items mentioned in that other discussion (flagging the non-ARC files appropriately with `–fno-objc-arc`), you may want to think about the rules outlined in the [Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), notably the naming conventions for methods (at least if they're methods to be invoked by the ARC subclass).